# How to extract year from date format and find all years greater than

Tags: bash, shell, date, awk, format

I need to print all years greater than 1900 in a field. I have used to awk to get the field with the date. But I can not figure out how to use awk to pull only the years that are >=1900.

So far I pulled this field by entering this:

awk -F',' '{print $5}' presidents.csv

this gives me these dates

```
4/03/1893
4/03/1897
14/9/1901
4/3/1909
4/03/1913
4/03/1921
2/8/1923
4/03/1929
4/03/1933
12/4/1945
20/01/1953
20/01/1961
22/11/1963
20/1/1969
9/8/1974
20/01/1977
20/01/1981
20/01/1989
20/01/1993
20/01/2001
20/01/2009
Incumbent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   awk -F',' '{print $5}' presidents.csv | awk -F '/'  '$3 > 1900 { print $1"/"$2"/"$3 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  #instead of presidents.csv
 echo "
f1,f2,f3,f4,4/03/1893
f1,f2,f3,f4,4/03/1897
f1,f2,f3,f4,14/9/1901
f1,f2,f3,f4,4/3/1909
f1,f2,f3,f4,4/03/1913
f1,f2,f3,f4,4/03/1921" \
| awk -F',' '{print $5}' \
| awk '{split($0,lineArr,"/");if (lineArr[3] > 1900) print $0}'
14/9/1901
4/3/1909
4/03/1913
4/03/1921
```

Comment: Why would one want to do it this way when it can be done the way [Sridhar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3095460/sridhar) presented it as a one-liner while directly using the `presidents.csv` file?

Comment: This form is meant as a test bed. You can see the inputs, you can comment out anything you like, and you can see the outputs. So you can always comment out all of the `echo`, and put presidents.csv after `...print $5}'` AND you can put my 2nd awk statement on the same line. Best wishes and good luck!

Comment: What the OP is asking is not so complicated that it needs a "test bed' to be presented, especially in light of the output of the `awk` command shown in the OP, it was just a matter of filtering the initial output further while piping it back through another `awk` command.  Yes what you presented when modified to be useful does output the desired results however what Sridhar presented is not so complexed that it needs a "test bed" (or explanation).

Comment: You can change `print $0` to just `print`  With no data it will do the default action, `print $0`